# httpclient 4 how to get bytes

Tags: java, http, servlets

```
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/"); 

    System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

    // Create a response handler
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
```

this will get responseBody as "string" , how to get btye[] with httpclient.execute(..) ?   the reason i want to get byte[] is because i want to write to some other outputstream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public byte[] executeBinary(URI uri) throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    entity.writeTo(baos);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Is it fine to leave baos not closed over here, or we need to explicitly close it by baos.close() ?

Comment: @AbhishekSen no, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330569/closing-a-bytearrayoutputstream-has-no-effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use the responseBody.getBytes() to get byte[].

Comment: this appears to create a characterset conversion issue

Answer (score 0):

Try HttpResponse.getEntity().writeTo(OutputStream)