# java: Flush stream while creating zip file

Tags: java, stream

I have code for create zip file in servlet like this :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos =null;
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
for(list  of file){
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(("somefile.extn"));

    other code for add entry in zip file

    bis.close();
}
baos.flush();
zos.flush();            
zos.close(); 
baos.close();

// Return bytes

baos.toByteArray();

// Write bytes to ServletOutputStream
```

Is there any problem if I flush & close `ByteArrayOutputStream` object (`baos`).

Thanks for looking here :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164598/java-is-bytearrayoutputstream-safe-without-flush-and-close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is redundant. All you need is

```
zos.close();
```

Closing the `ZipOutputStream` flushes and closes all the other streams it is wrapped around. See the Javadoc.

You don't even need the `ByteArrayOutputStream.` You should connect the `ZipOutputStream` directly to the servlet output stream.

Comment: if I don't add the zos.flush() after every entry, the file download process would stuck

Comment: @rileyss Using what code? If you're using the OP's code, that is definitely false, because of the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. If you're using other code, you're off-topic, and you need to ask another question.