# How to avoid throwing exception from finally block

Tags: java, exception

I don't want toJson to throw an Exception, but the finally block might throw it.
Would it be preferable to wrap the `bas.close()` in a try/catch block or should this be re-written using try-with-resources

```
public String toJson() {
    String json = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bas = null;

    try {
        bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.writeValue(bas, this);

        json = new String(bas.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.trace("Unable to parse JSON", e); 
    } finally {
        if (bas != null) {
            bas.close();
        }   
    }   

    return json;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should be rewritten as try-with-resources, this is prefereable for all auto-closable resources.

Comment: simple, don't throw one. but, honestly, I don't see a single way your current one would throw an Exception

Comment: @Stultuske [`ByteArrayOutputStream.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) is documented as throwing an exception "if an I/O error occurs".

Comment: You don't have to close a `ByteArrayOutputStream` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330569/closing-a-bytearrayoutputstream-has-no-effect

Comment: @AndyTurner but it is also documented to do nothing: [`ByteArrayOutputStream.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close()): "Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect. The methods in this class can be called after the stream has been closed without generating an IOException."

Comment: It should be added at last line in try, because if try block is executed till end, definitely it is only reason to close.

Comment: @Hulk sure, the human-readable doc says that. But the compiler requires you to handle an `IOException` if you invoke `close()`, whether using try-with-resources or not, because the class is declared in such a way that it is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it using the try-with-resources statement. Given below is an excerpt from the Oracle's tutorial on **[The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)** which clearly states the benefit of using it:

> Prior to Java SE 7, you can use a `finally` block to ensure that a
> resource is closed regardless of whether the `try` statement completes
> normally or abruptly. The following example uses a `finally` block
> instead of a try-with-resources statement:
>
> ```
> static String readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock(String path)
>                                                      throws IOException {
>     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
>     try {
>         return br.readLine();
>     } finally {
>         if (br != null) br.close();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> However, in this example, if the methods `readLine` and `close` both throw
> exceptions, then the method `readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock`
> throws the exception thrown from the `finally` block; the exception
> thrown from the `try` block is suppressed. In contrast, in the example
> `readFirstLineFromFile`, if exceptions are thrown from both the `try`
> block and the try-with-resources statement, then the method
> `readFirstLineFromFile` throws the exception thrown from the `try` block;
> the exception thrown from the try-with-resources block is suppressed.
> In Java SE 7 and later, you can retrieve suppressed exceptions; see
> the section Suppressed Exceptions for more information.

Using the try-with-resources statement, you can write your method as follows:

```
public String toJson() throws Exception {
    String json = null;

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.writeValue(bas, this);

        json = new String(bas.toByteArray());
    } 
    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd proabably go with something along the lines of:

```
public String toJson() {

    try (var bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.writeValue(bas, this);
        return new String(bas.toByteArray());
    }       
    catch (Exception ie) {
        throw new MyCustomJsonConverterException("Failed to render to JSON");
    }
}
```

*i.e.* map to a [RuntimeException type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) if you expect failure to serialize to JSON to be exceptional (a programming error). This is an instance method, after all, and all invariants of the class should already be enforced elsewhere. This way, you take the burden of checking for `null` from the caller.