# Java - ZipOutputStream within try-with-resources

Tags: java, try-with-resources, zipoutputstream

I have this Java code that creates and saves a zip file with a text file inside it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
        String s = "Hello, world!";
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("text_file.txt");
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(s.getBytes());
        zos.closeEntry();

        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("zip_file.zip")) {
            baos.writeTo(os);
            System.out.println("ZIP file created successfully");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it creates a zip file that is corrupted, so I cannot extract or even open the content within it.

Eventually I found out that if I manually close the `ZipOutputStream` by putting `zos.close()` after `zos.closeEntry()` the zip file is created successfully without corruption. Honestly this does not make any sense to me since I have declared the `ZipOutputStream` inside a [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, so I would have expected it to close automatically.

So it seems that the try-with-resource statement does not actually close the stream. Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

OS: Windows 10

Note: I used `ByteArrayOutputStream` because in the real scenario I have to create the zip file in memory, since I don't have a folder on a disk to rely on.

Comment: The automatic close of `zos` (and also `baos` but that doesn't make a difference) happens when you reach the _end_ of the outer TWR body, which is _after_ the inner TWR where you write the contents of `baos` to `zip_file.zip`. At the inner TWR `zos` has not been closed, and thus the contents of `baos` are not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was misplacing the `ByteArrayOutputStream` object: I should have not closed it by placing it inside the try-with-resource statement because, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330569/closing-a-bytearrayoutputstream-has-no-effect), `ByteArrayOutputStream` is purely memory based so the allocated memory will be released automatically by the garbage collector.

The following code produces the desired result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
        String s = "Hello, world!";
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("text_file.txt");
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(s.getBytes());
        zos.closeEntry();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }

    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("zip_file.zip")) {
        baos.writeTo(os);
        System.out.println("ZIP file created successfully");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `try-with-resources` *does* close the `ZipOutputStream`. It's just that it closes the zip stream after you copy its content to the `FileOutputStream`. How do you expect work that happens after the file has been closed to affect the content of the file?

I recommend replacing the `ByteArrayOutputStream` with the `FileOutputStream`. What need do you have to buffer?

```java
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("zip_file.zip");
     ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os)) {
  String s = "Hello, world!";
  ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("text_file.txt");
  zos.putNextEntry(entry);
  zos.write(s.getBytes());
  zos.closeEntry();
}
System.out.println("ZIP file created successfully");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used ByteArrayOutputStream over FileOutputStream because in the real scenario I have to create the zip file in memory, since I don't have a folder on disk to rely on (sorry, probably I should have mentioned it in my question).

Comment: @thwomp68 That still doesn’t make a lot of sense. You are just holding these compressed files in memory indefinitely until someone wants to decompress the content again?

Answer (score 0):

To keep everything in same Try-catch, another approach is to **finish & flush the ZipOutputStream** before using the content of ByteArrayOutputStream inside it (which can be incomplete, this is why it may generate corrupted zip), for example :

```
 try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
    //codes insert into zip
    zos.finish(); //finish writing
    zos.flush(); //flush any buffer inside
    //use baos 
 } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
 }
```